# Time ordering on Kelydsh countour

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, wick-theorem

I want to compute a time-ordering product but I have a question concerning this time ordering product.
First, we consider A,E,I,L,N,O and V some second quantized operators without specifing what operators they are.  Let $$t_{1}>t_{2}>t_{3}>t_{4}>t_{5}>t_{6}>t_{7} $$.
I want to compute this time ordering product :

$$<T_{k}[A_{t1^+}E_{t3^-}I_{t7^-}L_{t6^-}N_{t2^+}N_{t2^-}O_{t5^+}O_{t5^-}V_{t4^-}]>$$
Here $T_{k}$ is the time ordering on a Keldysh countour. The Keldysh contour goes from −∞ to +∞ (+
time label) and back from +∞ to −∞ (− time label).

[image]

We consider also that the operators are bosonic. This time ordering product contains 9 operators and the operators are written in Heisenberg representation.
Since I don't know what these operators are, there are many pairing possible, I am planning so to use the wick theorem to do this (although it will be very fastidious) but I don't know how to use the wick theorem with an odd number of operators. Usually, the time ordering product I encounter is always with an even number of operators.

My questions are :

How can I use the wick theorem with an odd number of operators?
Is there another method to compute this quantity (since there are 9 operators there are so many pairing possible...)?

Comment: Are these creating/annihilation operators? What is the averaging -over states with a fixed number of particles or is there a BE condensate involved? It also seems that your questions have nothing specific to Keldysh.